# How to modify the contents of local storage for a domain from a console app?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, console-application

I have a signature pad connected to a client machine which returns the signature as a base64 string. The signature is collected from the pad using a C# console application.

I want my web application to get that base64 string and update a PDF file stored on the server.

I tried to store the base64 string on a file on the disk but I was not able to access that file using JavaScript without user intervention.

How to access that base64 string which is stored inside my console application from the web application ?

EDIT: I am using IE11 as my browser

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:local-storage].

Comment: I want to modify the local storage to store that base64 string using my console app

Comment: Nothing in your question talks about modifying `localStorage`. It talks about reading from local storage (a file) and sending data to a server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data sent to your server from a page loaded in a standard web browser, user intervention is going to be necessary. Anything else is going to be nefarious, buggy, or both.

Instead, your console application can just send the data to your server directly, which seems like the simplest solution. (You'll obviously want to be sure the user is well aware of this process.)

If you need to integrate with a standard web browser, which will require user intervention, you can probably do better than a file. For instance, your console application can put the string in the clipboard; then the user just pastes it into an `input` and sends the form that `input` is in off to the server.

Comment: I will go with directly updating the file on the server from my console app. The customer wants minimum number of clicks as possible.